# Need a sequence number for every row in MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

So I found this great use:

```
SELECT (@row:=@row+1) AS ROW, ID  
FROM TableA ,(SELECT @row := 0) r   
ORDER BY ID DESC
```

The `@row:=@row+1` works great, but I get the row ordered by the ID.

My tables look more like this:

```
SELECT (@row:=@row+1) AS ROW, ID , ColA, ColB, ColC
FROM TableA 
JOIN TableB on TableB.ID = TableA.ID
JOIN TableC on TableC.ID = TableA.ID 
WHERE ID<500
,(SELECT @row := 0) r   
ORDER BY ID DESC
```

**Note:** 
I noticed that `if I remove the JOINs I DO get the requested result` (In Which `ROW` is the sequential number of each row, no matter the ORDER BY of ID). The first example works great but for some reaosn, the JOINs mess it up somehow.

so I get this:

```
ROW  | ID  
3      15  
2      10  
1      2
```

What I am after is:

```
ROW  | ID  
1      15  
2      10  
3      2
```

Here's the **[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8a511/6)**

So it basically seems that the row number is evaluated before the `ORDER BY` takes place. I need the `ORDER BY` to take place after row was given.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Remove the `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT (@row:=@row+1) AS ROW, ID  
FROM table1 ,(SELECT @row := 0) r
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1bcb9/1)

Then if you want to use an `ORDER BY` wrap the query in another `SELECT`:

```
select *
from 
(
  SELECT (@row:=@row+1) AS ROW, ID  
  FROM table1 ,(SELECT @row := 0) r
) x
order by row
```

Or if you leave the `ORDER BY` on the query, then you can see the way the row number is being applied by simply playing with either `DESC` or `ASC` order - [See Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1bcb9/18)

If you use `DESC` order

```
SELECT (@row:=@row+1) AS ROW, ID  
FROM table1, (SELECT @row := 0) r
order by id desc;
```

the results are which appears to be the result you want:

```
ROW | ID
----------
1   | 15
2   | 10
3   | 2
```

If you use `ASC` order:

```
SELECT (@row:=@row+1) AS ROW, ID  
FROM table1 ,(SELECT @row := 0) r   
ORDER BY ID;
```

the results are:

```
ROW | ID
----------
1   | 2
2   | 10
3   | 15
```

Edit, based on your change, you should place the row number in a sub-query, then join the other tables:

```
select *
from
(
  SELECT (@row:=@row+1) AS ROW, ID  
  FROM Table1,(SELECT @row := 0) r   
  order by ID desc
) x
JOIN Table2 
  on x.ID = Table2.ID;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8a511/10)

Comment: Sorry, I had to unmark your answer because admins did not allow me to ask in another question. The thing is that when JOINs are involved, it somehow messes the result. so that ID=2 always gets the ROW=1 and ID=15 get ROW=3. explained in the :edit:

Comment: @ted well that is a separate question from the original one you asked.  please create a sql fiddle with some sample data

Comment: I am sorry about that bluefeet, it was moderators decision

Comment: @Ted see my edit, you will want to use a subquery to assign the row number and then join on it.

Comment: @Ted can you explain "moderators decision"? Are you getting the message "we are no longer accepting questions from this account"? If so, [please read this in full](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers).

Comment: I decided to mark as answered and asked a new question with the modifications. It was closed as a duplicate of this thread.

Answer (score 4):

I dont find any problem with your query

```
SELECT (@row:=@row+1) AS ROW, ID  
FROM table1 ,(SELECT @row := 0) r   
order by ID desc
```

## [SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ebb16/1)