# Need a sequence number for rows in query

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Need a sequence number for every row in MySQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12707646/need-a-sequence-number-for-every-row-in-mysql-query)

So I found this great use:

```
SELECT (@row:=@row+1) AS ROW, ID  
FROM TableA ,(SELECT @row := 0) r   
ORDER BY ID DESC
```

My tables look more like this:

```
SELECT (@row:=@row+1) AS ROW, ID , ColA, ColB, ColC
FROM TableA 
JOIN TableB on TableB.ID = TableA.ID
JOIN TableC on TableC.ID = TableA.ID 
,(SELECT @row := 0) r   
ORDER BY ID DESC
```

The @row:=@row+1 works great, but I get the row ordered by the ID.

so I get something more like this:

```
ROW  | ID  
3      15  
2      10  
1      2
```

What I am after is:

```
ROW  | ID  
1      15  
2      10  
3      2
```

Note: I noticed that `if I remove the JOINs I DO get the requested result` (In Which `ROW` is the sequential number of each row, no matter the ORDER BY of ID)

It basically seems that the row number is evaluated before the ORDER BY takes place. I need the ORDER BY to take place after row was given.

Any idea regarding how I can achieve that, and what do the JOINS do that messes it up?

Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need the ORDER BY to take place after row was given.

Then try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
   SELECT (@row:=@row+1) AS ROW, ID , ColA, ColB, ColC
    FROM TableA 
    JOIN TableB on TableB.ID = TableA.ID
    JOIN TableC on TableC.ID = TableA.ID 
    ,(SELECT @row := 0) r 
) t
ORDER BY ROW ASC
```