# Select last 3 rows from a unoredred table in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I want to select last 3 rows of my table and no id is defined and table is not sorted either. Put it this way without using order clause or I just want to reverse the records of my non ordered table.

Comment: Could you please give some details, table representation, and what you already tried ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get SELECT results ordered by "row id" in mySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18833661/get-select-results-ordered-by-row-id-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
SET @rownum:=0;

SELECT *
FROM (SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 as rownum,*
      FROM yourTable) t1
ORDER BY rownum DESC
LIMIT 3;
```

Comment: Hi Ankit, for which version this syntax is applicable?

Comment: I think this solution is not depend on any version.